# Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known native property using angular2-webpack-starter

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I have problem using Angular2 Router, and I can't work it out.

This is my index.html

```
<html lang="">
<head>
  <title>Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2990 from @AngularClass</title>

  ...
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <!-- base url -->
  <base href="/">
  <!--
    Angular 2
    ES6 browser shim
  -->
  <script src="/lib/es6-shim.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <app>
    Loading...
  </app>

  ......
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.ts:

```
/*
 * Angular 2 decorators and services
 */
import {Directive, Component, View, ElementRef} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RouteConfig, Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
/*
 * Angular Directives
 */
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

import {Home} from '../components/home/home';
import {Banner} from '../components/banner/banner';
import {PickVideo} from '../components/pickvideo/pickvideo'


/*
 * App Component
 * Top Level Component
 */
@Component({

  selector: 'app',

  directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink, Home, Banner ],

 ...
  template: `
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <banner></banner>
    </header>
    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
  `
})

@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/',            redirectTo: 'home'},
  { path: '/home',                  as: 'Home',          component: Home },
  { path: '/pick-video',           as: 'PickVideo',       component: PickVideo}
])
```

When page loads, it will redirect to Home, I import ROUTER_DIRECTIVES at home.ts

Inside my home.ts, I have a breadcrum.ts, which has html code like this:

```
  <li class="active">
    <a [routerLink]="['Home']">NAME YOUR APP</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a [routerLink]="['PickVideo']">PICK YOUR VIDEOS</a>
  </li>
```

I also import ROUTER_DIRECTIVES at breadcrumb.ts

but when I open the browser, the exception given like this:

> Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known native property in
>   Breadcrumb > ol:nth-child(0) > li:nth-child(1) >
>   a:nth-child(1)[[routerlink]=['Home']]

What I did:

I checked online, it says the directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] is missing, but I have add this line of code at both app.ts, home.ts, breadcrumb.ts, it's not working, any advise?

I am using the [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)

Comment: It looks like something in your webpack config is lowercasing your HTML

Comment: I had the same problem using `html-minifier`. Adding the option `caseSensitive: true` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these

directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] in the main component
directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink] in the child components

Comment: Where should these be imported from?

Comment: import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';